# SlickGrid_CheckBox Editors Single Click

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am using SlickGrid V2.2, I m using slick editor and formatter for checkbox, to check checkbox it takes double click, I trying to make it single click. I tried with autoEdit: true, still its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try setting the grid option: enableCellNavigation: true.
I think this fixed the problem for me.